# My code works well in IE but fails in chrome

Tags: jquery, struts

```
$(function() {
    $("#confRoomID").combobox();
});
```

where confRoomID is the style id of the struts html select tag. The drop down is shown fine in IE but its failing in chrome. I dont know why? Kindly let me know if someone has any idea why it is happening so?

I can see the combo box in chrome, but once I click on it the page reloads itself and the drop down is shown for a fraction of a second and it goes away and the original page with combo box is once again shown.

I thought the following code may be helpful to answer the question.

```
.ui-autocomplete-associatesearch { height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;width: 250px;}

.ui-slider { position: absolute; text-align: left; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle { position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 1.2em; height: 1.2em; cursor: default;background-color: #F0F0F0; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range { position: absolute; z-index: 1; font-size: .7em; display: block; border: 0; background-position: 0 0; }

.ui-slider-horizontal { height: .8em; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle { top: -.3em; margin-left: -.6em; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range { top: 0; height: 100%; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min { left: 0; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-max { right: 0; }

.ui-slider-vertical { width: .8em; height: 100px; }
.ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-handle { left: -.3em; margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: -.6em; }
.ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-range { left: 0; width: 100%; }
.ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-range-min { bottom: 0; }
.ui-slider-vertical .ui-slider-range-max { top: 0; }

.ui-state-default
{
border: 1px solid #d8dcdf;
font-weight: bold;
color: #004276;
background-image: url(../../images/menu_down.gif);
margin-bottom: -.3em;}.ui-slider-handle{background-image: url();}
```

.....

```
$(function() {
$("#confRoomID").combobox();

$("#slider").css("background","#8F8B8B");         
$("#slider" ).slider({
    value:800,
    min: 0,
    max: 4000,
    step: 200,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#floor_image').mapster('resize', ui.value, 0, 1000);
    }
});

var areas = [];
$('area').each(function() {
    var data,area = $(this),
        fillColor = area.data('fillColor'),
        stroke= area.data('stroke');
    if (fillColor || stroke) {
        data = {
            key: area.attr('confroomid'),
            staticState: true
        };
        if (fillColor) {
            data.fillColor = fillColor;
        }
        if (stroke) {
            data.stroke = stroke;   
        }
        areas.push(data);
    }
});
$('#floor_image').mapster({
    singleSelect: true,
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    fadeInterval: 50,
    mapKey: 'confroomid',
    areas: areas
});


$('#floor_image').mapster('resize', 200, 0, 1000);
});

function process()
{   
if(document.forms[0].confRoomID.value <= 0) {
    alert('Please select Conference Room');
    return false;
}
document.forms[0].param.value = 'locateConfRoom';
document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

html code

```
<div id="container" style="padding:10px;">

<div id="map_demo">
                                              <img id="floor_image" 
                                        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/portLayoutAction.do?param=getFloorMap&floorMapURL=${confRoomBean.floorMapUrl}" 
                                        usemap="#floor" style="width: 4000px;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is missing a closing parenthesis (and semicolon) at the end.  Add `);`

Comment: IE works but Chrome doesn't??? LIES!!!

Comment: @cale_b...yeah i missed that while framing the question..added now...any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have provided. http://jsfiddle.net/wyQ8v/

Comment: If there's no JavaScript errors, your HTML may be invalid. Some browsers are more forgiving about invalid HTML than others. Check Chrome's debugger and see if the DOM structure it uses matches up to the HTML you've written.

Comment: It might be that you're trying to run combobox, before the appropriate JS library has been loaded (although this shouldn't happen, per `$(document).ready`). Are you by any chance using `defer` attribute? Can you please `console.log($.fn.combobox)` before the initialization of it?